# Issue in registering custom function in hibernate 6.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-mapping, spring-boot-3, hibernate-6.x

I am upgrading an application from springboot version to 3.1.2 and hibernate 6.2.
In Hibernate5 , we registered few custom sql functions like below:
Public class CustomPostgresDialect extends PostgrsSQL95Dialect

registerFunction("array_remove", new SQLFunctionTemplate(ListArrayType.INSTANCE, "areay_remove(?1,?2)"));

In Hibernate 6.2, I am trying to use functioncontributer like below

functionRegistry.registerPattern("array_remove","array_remove(?1,?2)", ListArrayType.INSTANCE));

But in the above statement, the registerPattern() expects the basic java return type in the third parameter. How to add ListArrayType as the return type?

I am using hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62 version

Comment: refer this [hibernate-6-custom-functions](https://aregall.tech/hibernate-6-custom-functions) blog

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.